# Naming multiple views in Xcode with StoryBoard

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a story board with a UIViewController.  The viewController has many views
In Xcode/StoryBoard - all views appear as "View".  This is very annoying as I can not distinguish them.    - I would like to rename them as View1, View2 etc so that I can tell them apart in Xcode.

How can I do that [image: Xcode Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it - 
This is done via the Label in the Identity Inspector Tab